# How to fix SMART Hard Disk Error (301)?

Tags: hard-drive

Today when I opened my laptop, it displays the message `smart hard disk error 301` and it tells me to run diagnostic test and gives me options on what to do. But the problem is that it passes the quick test but fails full test which runs only up to 18%. It also runs very very slow and at times when I have managed to switch on, it freezes and I think its because the processor has over heated.

Is the problem associated with hard drive or processor or both things need fixing. How do i fix this?

Comment: Probably a hard disk issue. Is your computer running slower than usual. If possible, run diagnostics in a rack on another machine

Answer (score 1):

You "fix" a failing drive by replacing it with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check for bad blocks,
I am new here so please ignore my mistakes... thnx
first boot into live boot mode with any linux distro
open terminal
write `sudo fdisk -l` and check your drive name
use e2fsck

```
sudo e2fsck --help

sudo e2fsck -cpvf /dev/sdx
```

where
"x" is your hard drive 
"c" is check for bad blocks
"p" is for auto repair
"v" verbose
"f" for force check even clean block
and you should be patient because it takes time.
if any error such as 
"use it without -a or -p"
then use

```
sudo e2fsck -cfvy /dev/sdx
```

it happened with me.